Custom git Server error responses on receive-pack and upload-pack
I am writing a very basic git server that can handle push once in a life cycle and clone.
This is for experimental and educationsal purposes only.
Here are the apis writen in go
http.HandleFunc("/git/asd.git", handleRequest)
http.HandleFunc("/git/asd.git/git-upload-pack", handleRequest)
http.HandleFunc("/git/asd.git/git-receive-pack", handleReceiveRequest)  

Please excuse my very very static example.
The problem is that I am unable to send the correct response from the server to the git cli client for both upload-pack and receive-pack.
Here is the code for receive-pack handler
func handleReceiveRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if _, err := io.Copy(buf, r.Body); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error reading request body: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    packIndex := bytes.Index(buf.Bytes(), []byte("PACK"))
    if packIndex == -1 {
        http.Error(w, "PACK signature not found in request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        fmt.Println("PACK signature not found in request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Expires", "Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT")
    w.Header().Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", fmt.Sprintf("application/x-git-receive-pack-result"))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    w.Write(packetWrite("unpack ok\n"))
    w.Write(packetWrite("ok refs/heads/master\n"))
    _, _ = w.Write([]byte("0000"))
}

w.Write(packetWrite("unpack ok\n"))
w.Write(packetWrite("ok refs/heads/master\n"))
w.Write([]byte("0000"))

This is the response that I got by mimicking the same steps in gogs. by from my handler Git complains error: failed to push some refs to <REMOTE>. i have also tried some other formats as response, but all get the same response.
<oldhash> <newhash> <branchref> 
0000

<oldhash> <newhash> <branchref> ok
0000

<newhash> <branchref> ok
ok <branchref>
0000

Now for the upload-pack I have similar issue as well. I am sending the response wrong it seems.
Git cli client complains fatal: protocol error: bad pack header if I send the following response in upload-pack
    _, _ = w.Write(packetWrite(fmt.Sprintf("ACK %s\n", <HASH>)))
    _, _ = w.Write([]byte("0000"))
    _, err = io.Copy(w, packReader)

I tried to run the server. I expect to successfully handle receive-pack and upload-pack apis and show success on git cli client.
both receive-pack and upload-pack are failing with error messages

random point: did you try adding a trailing \n in w.Write([]byte("0000\n")) ?

Have you read this and this? I'm triggered by your «… the response that I got by mimicking the same steps in gogs … have also tried some other formats as response»–I mean, it looks like you're trying to sort-of reverse-engineer or second-guess an openly documented protocol. Also do not forget that Git is a F/OSS program so you can just see how it parses your stuff and also you can instrument its code to trace its parsing, if so needed.

@LeGEC Yes I did.

@kostix Thanks. I had read those. For the upload-pack, the "0000" was not required. But still the receive-pack does not work.

FWIW: on error cases, your messages do not follow the documented "error packet" format (you do a plain fmt.Fprintf(w, "My mesage") instead of w.Write(packetWrite("ERR My message\n"))). Also, double check if your packetWrite() function has no corner cases that would create an invalid pkt-line.
